# Did Youtube and Wikipedia use a PHP-framework?

Tags: php, frameworks

I know that Youtube and Wikipedia was developed with PHP.

However, i wonder if the coders used a framework?

Or did they write it from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YouTube is almost entirely written in Python.

Comment: The original one was written in Php. Do you think they used a framework?

Comment: Where did you find that information? YouTube has always been written in python, as far as I know. http://www.slideshare.net/didip/super-sizing-youtube-with-python

Comment: check Here: Its in PHP only. 

https://builtwith.com/youtube.com

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia is [MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Main_Page), you can see the source for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

YouTube is [mostly python](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2006-December/070323.html)