# how to generated automatically a web page from header? AJAX/ASP/PHP/ETC

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, web, asp-classic

i want to know is there is a possibility to build a code/script etc (never mind in which prog language) that will do the next thing. for instance if my main domain is www.alex.com
so when i will go to www.alex.com/**xxxyyyzzz** it will generate automatically a web page with some information(templete for all of the non excisting pages?) even if there is no "xxxyyyzzz" in the DB. in other words i need some kind of page generator when sublink is being requested.

thanks.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Comment: I guess you are looking 404 page not found. This can be easily set from htaccess file or from control panel If you have that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you heard about [frameworks](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=what+are+php+frameworks&oq=what+are+php+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3j69i62l2.3762j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)?

A framework can do what you are looking for. Depending on the url, they can generate your page.

Here is a great one - [codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter)

Another one - [yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/).

Comment: thanks everyone for the fast comments what i really want to do is :
if you have YouTube link that look like that:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kJN7aqF68HQ
so when you will enter www.mydomain.com/watch?v=kJN7aqF68HQ you will get the same video.. but it will be generated dynamically because i don't have all the YouTube db..

Comment: Yes you should use a framework. That would be best. Though youtube is written in python, as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437400/did-youtube-and-wikipedia-use-a-php-framework) says.

Comment: im trying to set it up now

Comment: maybe wordpress framework?

Comment: Not heard of that. Look on [codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter) (Just my opinion)..

Comment: And hoping this answers your question, can you accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

If using PHP and Apache:

Use a .htaccess file similar to this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css|woff|ttf|svg|eot)
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?route=$1 [QSA]
```

This will mean if a user goes to www.alex.com/xxxyyyzzz, apache will internally route this to www.alex.com/index.php?route=xxxyyyzzz

In a PHP file you can find the route using something like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['route']))
    $route = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'route', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
```

and then based on different values include a different file. Don't do something like `include $route;` as someone could request any file they wanted. You could have an array with possible values and if it matches the array key then include the the value of the array at that key.